# Is it possible to use free open source font in logo Professional

Tags: fonts

I want to make logo with free open source font like ( Roboto , Lato...)

What is the license for such fonts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Google Fonts, you can find the license for each font by clicking on the name and looking under the Further Information section in the bottom right hand corner of the screen. I looked at both of the fonts you mentioned and it looks like Roboto is under the Apache License, Version 2.0 and Lato is under the Open Font License.

Here are the links to both of those licenses according to Google Fonts:

**Apache License, Version 2.0** : http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

**Open Font License** : http://scripts.sil.org/cms/scripts/page.php?site_id=nrsi&id=OFL_web

Find the font you want to use for sure, and read the license information that is provided with it. I know this is not the most exciting part of our jobs, but it is a necessary step that will save you from the incorrect interpretation of people who do not know all the details of your specific use case.

Hope this helps!